# Unable to install phpMyAdmin on CentOS 7

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, centos, php-7.4

Recently we updated CentOS 7 using `yum update -y` and post that we are facing several issues.

Now even after trying to install older version of php56 it is giving the same.

Error on trying install phpMyAdmin on CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

```
[root@***** install]# yum install phpmyadmin
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.rackspace.com
 * updates: mirror.fileplanet.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-zip-1.18.2-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: php(api) = 20131106-64
           Installed: php-common-7.4.4~RC1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-modular-test)
               php(api) = 20190902-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-19.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-zip-1.18.2-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identified a proper working solution towards this, thanks for [Techmint](https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-7-in-centos-6/)

Since I had install php7.4.4RC1, the subordinate packages was supposed to install from same repo and not different repository, in my case **remi-php74** is the correct one

**Steps**

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php74
yum install php-zip -y
yum install phpMyAdmin -y
```

**yum-utils** gave **yum-config-manager** to easily configure default remi repository of php74

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>       Installed: php-common-7.4.4~RC1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-modular-test)
> ```

Why have you this package installed ?

For a proper installation, please follow the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

BTW, latest phpMyAdmin version (5.0.2) requires at least PHP version 7.1.

Comment: How can I downgrade this package?

Comment: yes, or simply remove it to cleanup your system before a proper installation